# Question about a problem in affine geometry

Tags: affine-geometry, projection

I am trying to solve the following problem, but I don't have any clue about how to solve it, since in class we haven't even seen the "affine geometry" part of the Michèle Audin's book: Geometry.

The problem is this:

Let $E$ a vector space and let $\mathcal{F} \subset E$ be an affine subspace of $E$ not containing $0.$ Prove that the projection
$$p:E-\{0\} \to P(E)$$ restricts to an injective map from $\mathcal{F}$ to $P(E).$

According to the definition of the book, a set $\mathcal{F}$ is an affine subspace of a vector space if there is an element $A \in \mathcal{F}$ s.t. $\Theta_A(\mathcal{F})$ is a vector subspace of $E.$ One can prove that you can choose any point $x \in \mathcal{F}$ and you'll obtain $\Theta_A(\mathcal{F})=\Theta_x(\mathcal{F}).$

In the other hand, I am assuming that the projection map is s.t. $v \mapsto [v] \in P(E).$

Now, let $v,w \in \mathcal{F}$ s.t. $p(v)=p(w).$ That is, $[v]=[w]$, that is, $v=\lambda w$ for some nonzero $\lambda.$ We have that $\Theta_v(\mathcal{F})$ is a vector subspace of $E.$

But I can't find information here to tell that $v=w$. How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's $\Theta_A(\mathcal F)$?

Comment: In the Audin's book, the definition states that an affine space $\mathcal{E}$ is endowed by some map $\Theta: \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{E} \to E$ that associates each vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ with a pair of points $(A,B)$ of $\mathcal{E}.$ For all $A\in \mathcal{E},$ the partial map $\Theta_A (B)=\overrightarrow{AB}$ is a bijection.

Comment: You've done a great deal of the work already! Assuming that $v=\lambda w$ with $\lambda\ne1$ and that $\mathcal G=\Theta_A(\mathcal F)$ is a subspace of $E$, can you prove that $-A\in \mathcal G$? and then conclude that $0\in \mathcal F$ (and thus derive a contradiction)?

Comment: @GregMartin We have $0 \in \mathcal{G},$ (bc $\mathcal{G}$ is a vector space). But $0=\overrightarrow{AA}= \Theta_A (A).$ Since $\mathcal{G}=\{\Theta_A(B): B \in \mathcal{F}\},$ we conclude that $A \in \mathcal{G}.$ Then, $-A \in \mathcal{G}$ bc this is closed under scalar multiplication. Right? Now I can't see how does this imply that $0 \in \mathcal{F}$ by assuming $\lambda \neq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Greg Martin said you already did it. The difference $w-v$ always belongs to the subspace, so if $v=\lambda w$ with $\lambda \neq 1$, you have that $w-v=(1-\lambda)w$ is in the subspace.
This is a contradiction, since dividing out $1-\lambda$ you would obtain that $w$ is in the subspace.

Comment: But I began my proof assuming that $v,w \in \mathcal{F}.$ Hence automatically $v,w\in \Theta_A(\mathcal{F})$. Isn't it? Why $w\in \Theta_A(\mathcal{F})$ is a contradiction then?

Comment: Not true, you have that w-A and v- A are in the vector space (and so is v-w). A is just a point in F, not a vector. Maybe a drawing helps.

Comment: I finally understand it. I could solve succesfully the problem. Thanks